# Spark - Wrap an arbitrary RDD with using a ShuffledRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a Broadcast variable which I deserialize to obtain the an RDD along with its set of dependencies as following:

```
val taskBinary: Broadcast[Array[Byte]]
var (rdd, dep) = ser.deserialize[(RDD[_], ShuffleDependency[_, _, _])](
      ByteBuffer.wrap(taskBinary.value), Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader)
```

However, I want to wrap this rdd by a ShuffledRDD because I need to apply a custom partitioner to it and I am doing this by:

```
var wrappedRDD = new ShuffledRDD[_ ,_, _](rdd[_ <: Product2[Any, Any]], context.getCustomPartitioner())
```

but it results in an error:

> Error:unbound wildcard type
>         rdd = new ShuffledRDD[_ ,_, _ ](rdd[_ <: Product2[Any, Any]], context.getCustomPartitioner())
>                                                 ..................................^

The problem is that I don't know how to replace these wildcards with any inferred type as I its supposed to be dynamic and I have no idea what would be the inferred type of the original rdd. Any idea how I could resolved this?

Comment: First question - why on earth are you broadcasting an RDD???

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I am working on modified Spark core, and if you look into the source you will find out that the DAGscheduler actually broadcasts the RDDs to all the executors as a broadcast variable. It is deserialized back to RDD, as shown above, when a task is launched on the executor side. So now that I have explained the purpose, do you have a way of solving the issue?

Comment: Ok - I think this is relevant info that should perhaps have been added to the question. Usually when people try to broadcast RDDs they are on the wrong track ;-) That said, I have posted my solution in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I believe there are a couple of problems in your wrappedRDD. The reported error *"unbound wildcard type..."* relates to the fact that you have added a type definition to the `rdd` variable in the constructor call.

```
(rdd[_ <: Product2[Any, Any]], context.getCustomPartitioner())
```

should instead be

```
(rdd, context.getCustomPartitioner())
```

Furthermore, you need to provide a type for the `ShuffledRDD`. You could use `Any`,

```
var wrappedRDD = new ShuffledRDD[Any,Any,Any](rdd, context.getCustomPartitioner())
```

but I suspect what you really want to do, is to define a function that takes in the types and returns a type specific `ShuffledRDD` like this:

```
def wrapRDD[K:ClassTag, V:ClassTag, C: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[(K, V)]) = {
  new ShuffledRDD[K, V, C](rdd, context.getCustomPartitioner())
}

val wrappedRDD = wrapRDD[String, String, Combiner](rdd, context.getCustomPartitioner())
```

Comment: I tried to initialize the wrap the RDD like this
`var wrappedRDD = new ShuffledRDD[Any,Any,Any](rdd, context.getCustomPartitioner())`
 before as well but it results in the following error:
          
**Error: type mismatch;**
 `found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_0] where type _0
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_ <: Product2[Any,Any]]
      var wrappedRDD = new ShuffledRDD[Any,Any,Any](rdd, context.getCustomPartitioner())`
                                                    ^

Comment: As for the second solution you suggested, I really won't be knowing at the runtime what particular type of **ShuffledRDD** needs to be created, and hence thought of inititilizing with the **Any** type for its key, value and combiner. But as mentioned before, that does not compile.

Comment: The `found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_0] where type _0 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_ <: Product2[Any,Any]]` tells you that the rdd you are passing in does not have the right type. Perhaps you need to map your rdd to tuples first??

Comment: Also, what do you mean with _really won't be knowing at the runtime what particular type of ShuffledRDD needs to be created_? I understand that you don't know at compile time, but surely it's known at runtime.

Comment: How do I map my rdd to tuples ?
I tried `rdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2))` but it does not work.

Comment: My bad, I meant compile time not runtime.

Comment: How you convert it to tuples clearly depends on the type of the `rdd`, but it is a **required** to by of type `RDD[_ <: Product2[Any,Any]]` (a.k.a. a tuple2)  by the ShuffledRDD constructor, so you need to ensure that it is. My posted solution does in fact solve the problem you asked about. The fact that the rdd you pass in does not have the right type is a separate problem.